# customize the pentaho user console

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to customize the user console but I couldn't
I tested by changer the puc-login-logo.png to see if there's any changes but it didn't work.
I've deleted all my browser's caches and I've restarted the server !
And I didn't found the file called login.html as I saw in a tutorial in the internet.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU2ag.png)
Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: You need to give more detail. Which pentaho version? Where did you find that logo image file?

Comment: Blogs which you find on net are related with the older version of pentaho. Method of customizing PUC before Pentaho 7.1 and Pentaho 8.0 onwards are different.

Comment: I have Pentaho 7.1 and still have problems with customizing

Comment: @nsousa This is the path to the image file pentaho-solutions\system\common-ui\resources\themes\images